# Spliting Python string interpolation onto multiple lines

Tags: python, pep8

I've got a logging statement, something like:

```
get_logger().info(
    'Logger logging %s because we need to log it.' % response['foo']['bar']
)
```

With indentation it comes out well over 80 rows. If I could split it around the `%`, it would be fine.

How can I split this into multiple lines. (ideally without just putting `response['foo']['bar']` into a variable)

Comment: Put a `(` after the `%` - put the stuff on the next line and add a `)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_logger().info(
    'Logger logging %s because we need to log it.' 
    % response['foo']['bar']
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that should have been obvious, but I'm pretty new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

When using Python string formatting functionalities you can provide a `tuple`, not just a single value, as an input:

```
>>> "%d %d %d" % tuple(range(3)) # or just (0, 1, 2)
'0 1 2'
```

And then easily split your input tuple into multiple lines. You may, additionally, even assign the template string with percent-suffixed placeholders to a variable and use it later. An example would be:

```
>>> template = "The averaged temperatures of the last three days were %d, %d and %d"
>>> template % (22, 26, 23)
'The averaged temperatures of the last three days were 22, 26 and 23'
```

You can know more about Python string formatting in [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) (Python 3.5.4).

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth noting that, for logging,

```
get_logger().info(
    'Logger logging %s because we need to log it.' 
    % response['foo']['bar']
)
```

is the same as:

```
get_logger().info(
    'Logger logging %s because we need to log it.', 
    response['foo']['bar']
)
```

since the `debug()`, `info()`, etc . methods interpret `*args` as to be used for string formatting the message.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

In general for long strings, ones that ought to wrap around column 80, use parentheses, taking advantage of python's built-in string joining:

```
deeplyNested = True
thing = 'feedback'
class Contrived(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if deeplyNested:
            logger.info(
                ("Sometimes there's a lot to say in %s and you need to write"
                 " longer messages than what nicely fits in the 80 column"
                 " limit."),
                thing
            )
```